# Ошибка при сборке в CMake

Tags: linux, c, gcc, cmake, makefile

Не могу понять как правильно собрать статическую библиотеку с помощью `cmake`.
Моя цель состоит в следующем:

> 1) Собрать все хэадеры в общую библиотеку `.а`(все они лежат в папке
>   `/include`)
>
> 2) Переместить архив библиотеки в `/usr/local/lib/` или
>   `/usr/local/include` для общего пользования (желательно через `make install` при сборке).

Прилаживаю дерево проекта:

```
.
├── cmake-build-debug
│   └── CMakeFiles
│       └── clion-log.txt
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cmake_path
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.10.2
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeError.log
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── collections.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── collections_static.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── feature_tests.bin
│   │   ├── feature_tests.c
│   │   ├── feature_tests.cxx
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   └── untitled.dir
│   │       ├── build.make
│   │       ├── C.includecache
│   │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │       ├── cmake_clean_target.cmake
│   │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │       ├── depend.internal
│   │       ├── depend.make
│   │       ├── flags.make
│   │       ├── library.c.o
│   │       ├── link.txt
│   │       └── progress.make
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── libuntitled.a
│   └── Makefile
└── include
    ├── constant_status.h
    ├── simple_binary_tree.h
    ├── simple_linked_list.h
    ├── simple_queue.h
    └── simple_stack.h
```

Файл `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(collections)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

file(GLOB header_files "include/*.h")
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_static STATIC ${header_files})
include_directories("./include")

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${header_files}")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_static
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

При попытке сгенегрить `makeFile` через `cmake ..` получаю ошибки:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (set_target_properties):
>   set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
>   collections
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (target_link_libraries):   Cannot
>   specify link libraries for target "collections" which is not built
>   by this project.

Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: ЕМНИП я уже писал, что собирать что-либо из одних только хедеров — странно и по большей части лишено практического смысла... а ошибки из-за того, что `_static` то добавляешь к имени цели то убираешь... тут нужно определиться (скорее всего он не нужен)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, объясните почему это лишено смысла?

Comment: Современный язык Си устроен так, что для корректного использования того что было *определено* в другом *модуле транляции* необходимо это (*совместимо*) *объявить*. Традиционно эти объявления и выносятся в хедеры. Для библиотек (статических или динамических) здесь действуют те же правила, что и для обычных объектных файлов, поэтому библиотеки почти всегда поставляются вместе с хедерами...

Comment: Какие последствия будут если нарушать это правило зависит от того что именно у тебя в хедерах. Если там только процессорные инструкции и определения типов, то нет смысла собирать из них «библиотеку» — там не будет ничего интересного... Если же там определения, то почти наверняка ты получишь разнообразные проблемы времени линковки при попытке использовать эти хедеры вместе с библиотекой... так или иначе это почти наверняка не то, что ты хочешь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в хэадерах лежат обычные функции (когда писал их это казалось хорошей идеей). Я просто хочу получить к ним доступ с всех приложений в системе (при сборке). Что посоветуете? Нужно стараться использовать .с и только потом собирать библиотеку?

Comment: да, если кратко; все определения — в `*.c`, все объявления — в `*.h` и *.h установить в `<prefix>/include`... полно, если не разберёшься, наверное, только через несколько дней смогу расписать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в любом случае буду признателен.

Comment: как успехи? ещё остались какие-то вопросы?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, хорошого мало, пробовал решение NewView но наверное я не до конца все понял, поэтому успехи на том же уровне.

Comment: дык а реализацию в `*.c` файлы вынес?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, да, но ошибка не пропала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки уже описаны в комментариях. ключевые моменты:

- необходимо отделять определения сущностей от их объявлений
- надо внимательно следить за именованием целей сборки

как примерно должно выглядеть дерево проекта:

```
.
├── cmakelists.txt
├── constant_status.c
├── constant_status.h
├── simple_binary_tree.c
├── simple_binary_tree.h
├── simple_linked_list.c
├── simple_linked_list.h
├── simple_queue.c
├── simple_queue.h
├── simple_stack.c
└── simple_stack.h
```

отделение `*.h`-файлов в отдельный каталог обычно вызывает больше проблем, чем даёт пользы. 
при желании можно все исходники переместить в отдельный каталог `src`.
при этом хорошей практикой будет если у каждого подкаталога будет свой `CmakeLists.txt`.

### CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(version 3.5)
project(collections)

set(cmake_c_standard 99)

# использование file(glob ... ) для исходников — плохая практика см. документацию cmake
set( collections_srcs 
  constant_status.c simple_binary_tree.c simple_linked_list.c
  simple_queue.c simple_stack.c
)

# для хедеров это было бы допустимо, хотя имхо также не желательно
set( collections_hdrs 
  constant_status.h simple_binary_tree.h simple_linked_list.h
  simple_queue.h simple_stack.h
)

# желательно использовать какой-то свой подкаталог, чтобы избежать коллизей
# с системными хедерами (или из других проектов)
set( collections_header_path include/${project_name})

# суффикс `_static` бессмысленен если собираем только статическую библиотеку
add_library(collections static collections_srcs)

set_target_properties(collections PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${collections_hdrs}")
install(targets collections
        archive destination lib
        public_header destination include/${project_name})
```

### Как использовать

Для сборки и установки:

```
cmake /path/to/collection/sources && make && sudo make install
```

По-умолчанию префиксом для cmake'а является `/usr/local/` соответственно хедеры/библиотека будут установлены в `/usr/local/include/collections` и `/usr/local/lib/libcollections.a` соответственно. При данном способе установки администратор [localhost'а] **сам отвечает** за то что/куда/как/на сколько/итп установлено.

#### main.c

```
#include<simple_binary_tree.h>

int main (void) {
  simble_binary_tree bt;
  sbt_init (&bt);

  process_sbt (&bt);

  return 0;
}
```

Сборка:

```
gcc main.c -I/usr/local/include/collections -lcollections -o myCollectionsApp
```

Эти пути по-умолчанию включены в пути поиска системных компиляторов. Поэтому не обязательно указывать путь к библиотеке. Также если подправить хедеры и структуру проекта, то можно будет делать просто `#include<collections/simple_binary_tree.h>` и не передавать компилятору путь к хедерам в `-I`.

Comment: Получил ошибку об неверном количестве аргументов: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.

Comment: скорее всего что то не так с collections_hdrs, cmake ее как будто не видит.

Comment: @UjinUkr, наоборот — видит и раскрывает... просто кавычки пропустил...

Answer (score 0):

Начать с этого:

```
if(MSVC)
   set( lib_target "libname" )
else()
   set( lib_target "name" )
endif()

set(inst_hdrs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/mysharedheader.h
)
set(lib_hdrs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/header1.h)
set(lib_srcs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../src/mycode.c)

add_library( ${lib_target} STATIC ${lib_srcs} ${lib_hdrs} )
set_target_properties(${lib_target} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER ${inst_hdrs})

// VS_STARTUP_PROJECT - MSVC project settings - назначить запускаемый
// проект по умолчанию,
// если у вас нет исполняемых файлов, убрать
set( app_target "TestMyExec" )
add_executable( ${app_target} "../test/test.c" )
target_link_libraries( ${app_target} ${lib_target} )
set_property( DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT ${app_target} )
add_test( NAME test COMMAND ${app_target} )
```

Сам код инсталляции:

```
install ( TARGETS ${lib_target}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include"
)

install ( TARGETS ${app_target}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/test"
)
```